# Is this a UI-threading issue? Is there an easy way to fix it?

Tags: vb.net

I am communicating with a USB-HID device. It will successfully complete hundreds of send-receive requests but occasionally get a Null Exception error.

Is this a threading issue?

FormMain.vb:

```
myHidDevice.transmitPacket(Packet)
myHidDevice.resetEvent.WaitOne(6)
If myHidDevice.rxDataReady = True then
    ' Life is good
```

MyHidDevicePort.vb

```
Public Sub DataReceivedHandler(ByVal sender as Object, dataReceived as DataReceivedEventArgs)
    if dataReceived.data Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim rDataPacket As List(Of Byte) = dataReceived.data.ToList()
        For Each element in rDataPacket
            rxData.dataPacket(i) = element
        rxDataReady = True
        resetEvent.Set()
```

MySensorClass.vb

```
Public Overrides Function processPacket(ByRef rxStruct as rStruct, ByVal txPacket()) as Boolean
....
Select Case rxStruct.dataPacket(4)
    Case MOD_DISPLAY_SET_BRIGHTNESS
        rxData(0) = rxStruct.dataPacket(5)
    ...
```

at the rxData.dataPacket(i) = element I will get a NullReference error every now and then. I could enclose it in a try/catch statement, but I'd like to fix the root problem if possible.

This device is communicating to microcontrollers, and it is possible that they won't always give a value... but my feeling is this is some sort of UI threading issue. When debugging, even though there is a null exception, many times there actually does seem to be data in dataReceived.data.ToList(). Is there an easy way to place the whole data processing routine on a thread separate from the UI?

**Edit:** Changed code to match answer and give more info on where it is used. Still get NullReferenceExceptions after about 1,000 completed send/receive requests to the HID device.

Comment: Sounds like threading to me.  Most likely you are getting bit on access to rxData, but you'll need to show the code that consumes/reads from that list.  Have you tried wrapping acesses to that List in a SyncLock?

Comment: Your rxDataReady flag is vulnerable as well.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. Each sensor has its own class which accesses rxData in it's ProcessData method... so there are lots of places where I'm accessing this. I tried SyncLocking, but it's still popping up errors, maybe a BlockingCollection is what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog in the comments is too restricting, so I'll try this as an answer.  Unfortunately, there still isn't enough code to give a full answer.

Some sample unknowns:

What is `rxData` (a custome class, part of the SDK, a struct)?

Where does `i` come from in the code sample `rxData.dataPacket(i) = element`, I don't see it decalred or incremented.

Why is the form waiting on `myHidDevice.resetEvent.WaitOne(6)` and what does it do once it thinks there is sucess?

How/when does `processPacket` get called?

What I can recommend in general is that access to shared state be wrapped in a SyncLock.  And in your case, that includes both rxData and rxDataReady.

In your threaded event callback you need this:

```
SyncLock(syncRoot)
   For Each element in rDataPacket             
      rxData.dataPacket(i) = element
   next         
   rxDataReady = True         
   resetEvent.Set() 
End SyncLock
```

And in your Main form where you are waiting for a response you need to wrap access to the ready flag as well:

```
SyncLock(myHidDevice.syncRoot)
   If myHidDevice.rxDataReady = True then  

      ' do something that consumes the data read in the thread

   End If
End SyncLock
```

You have to watch for how long you hold the lock in the read and the write because you cannot be doing both at the same time.

Over all, I wouldn't be surprised if your code code be refactored a bit to make the thread issues easier to deal with.  A blocking queue / colletion as you suggested might be a good idea.  Just not enough is known of you design/code to give any more concrete advice.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid if I fully listed out all the code I would scare everyone away with a wall of text. There are about 50 different types of sensors/solenoids/screens communicating via a CAN bus, each has it's own class, address and strongly-typed values that have to match for the value to be accepted as a valid reply. The acquisition routine sends out a command and immediately waits for a reply: myHidDevice.resetEvent.WaitOne(6). We used a FTDI serial to USB adapter for the original code, we recently switched to a much faster HID device. My feeling is this happened before, but it was rare.

Comment: @svaha Ideally you want to deal with the threading at a higher level and leave your sensor/etc objects unaware of the threading.  Is your comm purely send-command/recv-response?  Or are there other unsolicited responses?  Can you have multiple commands pending at once?

Comment: In theory, it should be send-command/receive response. There's a timer that sets off a chain of requests every second. I think that, if some sensors don't respond it gets stuck waiting on them, and it takes longer than a second. It may be easier to make sure all requests take less than a second and abort any that don't.

Comment: If it is a simple send/recv the I suggest that your HIDDevice class should have a Send(packet) method and a corresponding Recv(timeout) As reponse method.  The callback/event should write to a BlockingCollection, and the Recv should read from that collection.  Do not expose any event handles, boolean ready flags etc.  You should not need them.  The code that calls Recv should be prepared to read and discard old response from a prior Send where waiting for the response was timed-out/abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is a possibility that your object may be *null*, placing it inside of a try-catch block would be the *incorrect* way of handling this situation, as that would be considered *coding by exception*.  Instead, do a null check on your object prior to setting it. e.g.

```
If Not dataReceived.data Is Nothing Then
   Dim rDataPacket As List(Of Byte) = dataReceived.data.ToList() 
End If
```

If your problem lyes with the individual array elements being null, you should also check them to ensure they exist before setting/accessing them.

Comment: I had added this before. I added it again and I STILL get ArgumentNullException. It still passes that condition but fails later on and... even more cryptic: I see values in the debugger. That's what made me think it's a UI threading issue or maybe the HID device is occasionally receiving multiple events.

Comment: ArgumentNullException is different than NullReferenceException.  Which one are you getting?